# Is it smart to use tasks on controller methods having a single backend call?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Is there any advantage of using **Task** on Controller method *having
a single backend call*?

(Ex: simple select from SQL server) like below

```
public Task<string> Get(int id)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
       return SimpleSelectFromDB();
    });
 }
```

rather than (synchronous)

```
 public string Get(int id)
 {
    return SimpleSelectFromDB();
 }
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any advantage of using Task on Controller method having a
>   single backend call?

Lets begin with the fact that calling `Task.Run` inside ASP.NET [is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). It can cause offloaded work to be terminated once an IIS recycle kicks in. If you want to offload to a background thread, use either `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` or [`AspNetBackgroundTasks`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) which register their work.

In your current example, you're doing work which is naturally asynchronous, such as invoking a call to your database. There's no need for a threadpool thread to do that, you can use naturally asynchronous API such as those that are provided by database providers such as Entity Framework (starting V6 and above) and leverage them. Those async API's nowadays come in the form of API's that either return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`, which conforms to the TAP (Task Asynchronous Pattern) which plays nicely with `async-await`.

Comment: Can you please specify this point
"It can cause offloaded work to be terminated once an IIS recycle kicks in"

Comment: Sure. Read [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is rarely any advantage to using `Task.Run()` in server-side code.

All you're doing is going off of one threadpool thread and on to a different one.

Instead, you should change the backend call to use non-blocking IO and `await` it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response,You meant to use Async and Await right?